# for-loop checking which date is what day(whether weekend or weekday)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, days

I am working on scheduler. Especially `date` part is too tricky for me.

I want to know the date is whether weekday or weekend. If I can, I want to group the weekday and weekend separately to count member index separately.

so, as the date array index increases, the date will be checked whether weekday or weekend, and cover member index numbers.

First question, why the return of this code is illegal?

Second, how can I know the date is what day?

```js
var member = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var dayArray = ['0','1','2,','3','4','5','6'];
var checkDay;

function setDate(yy, mm, dd){
  var date = new Date(yy, mm, dd);
  var setDate = new Date(date.getTime() + 3600000*9); // add milliseconds to optimize time zone
  return setDate;  
} 

var date = setDate(2020,5,5).getDay(); // set a date

console.log(date);

for(var d = 0; d< dayArray.length; d++){
  if(date = 0){
    var checkDay = "Sun";
    return checkDay;
  } else if(date = 1){
    var checkDay = "Mon";
    return checkDay; 
  } else if(date = 2){
    var checkDay = "The";
    return checkDay;
  } else if(date = 3){
    var checkDay = "Wed";
    return checkDay;
  } else if(date = 4){
    var checkDay = "Thu";
    return checkDay;
  } else if(date = 5){
    var checkDay = "Fri";
    return checkDay;
  } else if(date = 6){
    var checkDay = "Sat";
    return checkDay;
  }
}
console.log(checkDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement stops a loop only if it's inside the function. Or else, SyntaxError will be thrown.

```js
var member = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var dayArray = ['0','1','2,','3','4','5','6'];
var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "The", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]

function setDate(yy, mm, dd){
  var date = new Date(yy, mm, dd);
  var setDate = new Date(date.getTime() + 3600000*9); // add milliseconds to optimize time zone
  return setDate;  
} 

var date = setDate(2020,5,5).getDay(); // set a date

console.log(days[date]);
```

Using [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```js
var member = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var dayArray = ['0','1','2,','3','4','5','6'];

function setDate(yy, mm, dd){
  var date = new Date(yy, mm, dd);
  var setDate = new Date(date.getTime() + 3600000*9); // add milliseconds to optimize time zone
  return setDate;  
} 

var date = setDate(2020,5,5); // set a date

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {weekday: 'short'}))
```